# How to fetch vehicle owner information from registered number plate?

Tags: java, android, database, android-database

I'm working on an Android application where I need to fetch data from a particular website ("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102) but it shows captcha before submitting the query.

What should I do?

There are tons of applications available on playstore that does the same function but I don't know how they fetch the details from the government database.

Is there any trick or method through which I can retrieve the information and resolve the captcha at the same time?

If so: how do I use it?

Comment: The TOS says that you can't use for commercial use. if the other apps are legitimate. they must have gotten access to api. you may have to pay or register for api access.

Comment: It is not clear whether your question is `how to bypass captcha`, or `which API wil give me this data`.

Comment: Both .!!
i want to bypass the captcha if i'm using a crawler or if not then which api should i use to get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the APIs you are looking for are **PAID** ones .You can lookup the official details [here](https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/paidnrservices/) .

[This](https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/paidnrservices/forms/paidnr_access_application.pdf) is the UserID creation form for accessing the datas.

Comment: What should be approximately charged?